# Cerrar caja cuando las imagenes hayan sido vistas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quisiera lograr que cuando todas las imagenes hayan sido vistas se cierre la caja que las contiene id 'caja' , la caja la activo con jquery con el mismo boton que llamo a la imagen a ser mostrada, pero quiero poder abrir y cerrar la caja con javascript, cerrarla cuando hayan sido vistas todas las imagenes obvio.

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

```js
let historyElements= [ 'imagen1','imagen2','imagen3'];
for (let i=0;i < historyElements.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(openHistory,2000 * i,historyElements[i]);
}
function openHistory(historyName) {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName("history");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  document.getElementById(historyName).style.display = "block";  
}

/* Utilizo jquery para abrir la caja pero quisiera hacerlo todo con javascript */
$('.imagen').click(function(){
  $('.caja').css({
    "display": "flex"
  });
});
```

```css
.caja{
background-color: #ddd;
justify-content: center;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="imagen" onclick="openHistory('imagen1')">Imagen 1</button>

<button class="imagen" onclick="openHistory('imagen2')">Imagen 2</button>

<button class="imagen" onclick="openHistory('imagen3')">Imagen 3</button>


<div id="caja" class="caja">

<div id="imagen1" class="history">
<img src="https://www.wampstore.com/store/image/cache/data/Wamp/Products/Vallejo/Flat%20Red-900x900.jpg">
</div>

<div id="imagen2" class="history">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1218/4290/products/Solid-129-Purple_1400x.jpg?v=1464824795">
</div>

<div id="imagen3" class="history">
<img src="https://www.wampstore.com/store/image/cache/data/Wamp/Products/Vallejo/Deep%20Sky%20Blue-900x900.jpg">
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ejecutar el primer bucle una vez mas para que oculte todas las imagenes:
`<` ► `<=`

`for (let i=0;i <= historyElements.length; i++)`

Le pasas un parámetro a la función `openHistory` para ver si ha ya ha terminado de ver todas las imagenes

```
let bucleTerminado = i < historyElements.length ? true : false;
setTimeout(openHistory,1000 * i,historyElements[i],bucleTerminado);
```

Y antes de aplicar el `display: block;` compruebas el parámetro que le has pasado:

```
if(bucleTerminado){
    document.getElementById(historyName).style.display = "block"; 
}
```

---

### Edit despues de cambios del OP

Por lo que entiendo quieres que las imagenes/caja se cierren una vez se han visto todas. Así es como lo haría yo, con un array paralelo para marcar las imagenes que han sido vistas ya.

```
let historyElements= [ 'imagen1','imagen2','imagen3'];
let imagenesVistas= [false,false,false];
```

El código hace lo siguiente:

1. Se comprueba si esa imagen ha sido vista.
2. Si no ha sido vista entra en el `if` y se marca como vista y la muestra.
3. Se comprueba si todas las imágenes se han visto
4. Si todas las imágenes se han visto entra en el `if` y reinicia el `array` de imágenes vistas a `false` para volver a empezar.

Código:

```
if(imagenesVistas.includes(false) && imagenesVistas[historyElements.indexOf(historyName)] != true){
    imagenesVistas[historyElements.indexOf(historyName)] = true;
    document.getElementById("caja").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById(historyName).style.display = "block";
    if(!imagenesVistas.includes(false)){
      setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("caja").style.display = "none";
        for(let x=0;x<imagenesVistas.length;x++){
          imagenesVistas[x]=false;
        }
      },2000);
    }
  }
```

**Snippet entero:**

```js
let historyElements= [ 'imagen1','imagen2','imagen3'];
let imagenesVistas= [false,false,false];

function openHistory(historyName) {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName("history");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  if(imagenesVistas[historyElements.indexOf(historyName)] != true){
    imagenesVistas[historyElements.indexOf(historyName)] = true;
    document.getElementById("caja").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById(historyName).style.display = "block";
    if(!imagenesVistas.includes(false)){
      setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("caja").style.display = "none";
        for(let x=0;x<imagenesVistas.length;x++){
          imagenesVistas[x]=false;
        }
      },2000);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.caja{
  background-color: #ddd;
  justify-content: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="imagen" onclick="openHistory('imagen1')">Imagen 1</button>

<button class="imagen" onclick="openHistory('imagen2')">Imagen 2</button>

<button class="imagen" onclick="openHistory('imagen3')">Imagen 3</button>


<div id="caja" class="caja">

<div id="imagen1" class="history">
<img src="https://www.wampstore.com/store/image/cache/data/Wamp/Products/Vallejo/Flat%20Red-900x900.jpg">
</div>

<div id="imagen2" class="history">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1218/4290/products/Solid-129-Purple_1400x.jpg?v=1464824795">
</div>

<div id="imagen3" class="history">
<img src="https://www.wampstore.com/store/image/cache/data/Wamp/Products/Vallejo/Deep%20Sky%20Blue-900x900.jpg">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio pero no había describido el problema al 100% ya que necesito cerrar la caja y no la ultima imagen, ya edité la pregunta.

Comment: div con la id 'caja'

Comment: @Header90 He editado mi respuesta tras tu edición, espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo mucho la lógica de lo que necesitas hacer, pero funciona ( cambie el tiempo para que se note más )

```js
let historyElements= [ 'imagen1','imagen2','imagen3'];

for (let i=0;i < historyElements.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(openHistory,3000 * i,historyElements[i]);
}

function openHistory(historyName) {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName("history");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  document.getElementById(historyName).style.display = "block"; 
  if (historyName == historyElements[historyElements.length-1])
        setTimeout(hideHistory,3000 ,historyName);
}

function hideHistory(historyName) {
  document.getElementById(historyName).style.display = "none"; 
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<img id="imagen1" class="history" src="https://www.wampstore.com/store/image/cache/data/Wamp/Products/Vallejo/Flat%20Red-900x900.jpg">
<img id="imagen2" class="history" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1218/4290/products/Solid-129-Purple_1400x.jpg?v=1464824795">

<img id="imagen3" class="history" src="https://www.wampstore.com/store/image/cache/data/Wamp/Products/Vallejo/Deep%20Sky%20Blue-900x900.jpg">
```